# How to add an action only to Strings.xml files in Android in IntelliJIdea Plugin development

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I created a IntelliJIdea Plugin, using the actions entry in `plugin.xml` like

```
  <actions>
    <!-- Add your actions here -->
    <group id="AL.Localize" text="_Localize" description="Localize strings" >
      <add-to-group group-id="ProjectViewPopupMenu"/>

      <action id="AL.Convert" class="action.ConvertToOtherLanguages" text="Convert to other languages"
              description="Convert this strings.xml to other languages that can be used to localize your Android app.">

      </action>
    </group>
  </actions>
```

Using this setting, my action will appear after user right-click a file. Like this:
[image: right-click popup menu]

The problem is that the `Convert to other languages` menu shows all the time, I only want this menu show when user right-click on the `string.xml` file, like the `Open Translation Editor(Preview)` menu does. (`Open Translation Editor(Preview)` is a feature Android Studio introduced in [version 0.8.7](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio087released))

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to do this purely in XML, so somebody else feel free to chime in if you know of way, but there is a way to do this in Java.

In your action's update method, you can set whether the action is visible or not based on the name of the file using the action's `Presentation` object.  Here's an example based on the `ConvertToNinePatchAction` in Android Studio:

```
package com.example.plugin;

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public class ConvertToOtherLanguages extends AnAction {

    public ConvertToOtherLanguages() {
        super("Convert to other languages");
    }

    @Override
    public void update(AnActionEvent e) {
        final VirtualFile file = CommonDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE.getData(e.getDataContext());
        final boolean isStringsXML = isStringsFile(file);
        e.getPresentation().setEnabled(isStringsXML);
        e.getPresentation().setVisible(isStringsXML);
    }

    @Contract("null -> false")
    private static boolean isStringsFile(@Nullable VirtualFile file) {
        return file != null && file.getName().equals("string.xml");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        // Do your action here
    }
}
```

Then in XML, your action would look like this:

```
<action id="AL.Convert" class="com.example.plugin.ConvertToOtherLanguages">
    <add-to-group group-id="ProjectViewPopupMenu" anchor="last" />
</action>
```